# ORACLE Get_DLL for Constraint using index

Tags: oracle, constraints, ddl

I am trying to export some Constraint DDLs from Oracle like this :

```
EXECUTE DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM(DBMS_METADATA.SESSION_TRANSFORM,'STORAGE',false);
EXECUTE DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM(DBMS_METADATA.SESSION_TRANSFORM,'TABLESPACE',false);
EXECUTE DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM(DBMS_METADATA.SESSION_TRANSFORM,'SEGMENT_ATTRIBUTES',false);

EXECUTE DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM(DBMS_METADATA.SESSION_TRANSFORM,'SQLTERMINATOR',true);

 DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL
           ( 'CONSTRAINT',MYCONSTRAINT, ME);
```

I get

```
 ALTER TABLE "ME"."MYTABLE" ADD CONSTRAINT "MYCONSTRAINT" PRIMARY KEY
 ("COL1") ENABLE;
```

I want

```
ALTER TABLE "ME"."MYTABLE" ADD CONSTRAINT "MYCONSTRAINT" PRIMARY KEY ("COL1") USING INDEX MYINDEX);
```

I couldn't find any option in documentation for Oracle 11.2 :
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_metada.htm#BGBJBFGE

Any idea how to achieve this ?

Comment: Why does it matter? If you run the generated `alter` for a table that already has `MYINDEX` (or any appropriate index) then the constraint will still use it even if there is no `using index` clause. If you don't have that (or any) index then it will create an index with the same name as the constraint, using the default tablespace and its default storage since you've suppressed those. You can't then create `MYINDEX` on the same column; but in that situation if the `alter` did name the index then it would fail if as it doesn't exist.

Comment: Now that you mention it, you are right, it is useless. Which now makes me wonder why this option even exist. Anyway thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 0):

This might help, or get you very close:

```
SELECT REPLACE(dbms_metadata.get_ddl('CONSTRAINT', constraint_name, USER)
                 ,' USING INDEX '
                 ,' USING INDEX "' || index_name || '" ' ) ddl
  FROM user_constraints
  WHERE index_name IS NOT NULL
    AND constraint_name NOT LIKE 'BIN$%';
```